# Subscribing to the event of the "quiz" module of the Moodle CMS from its own plugin

Tags: moodle

Good afternoon, I am developing my own plugin (folder: local) for the **Moodle platform** version **"2023042400" - (4.2.2+)** on the **Windows platform**.

There was such a need to subscribe to the event of the standard module **"quiz"** called **"Send everything and finish"**.  I have a need to get all the wrong answers after completing the test and give out additional information in the interface, but for now I will be happy only to sign the data.

The programming language used is **"PHP"**.

> P.S. I am new to this environment, so I will be happy to describe the solution in detail.

**Path to file:** \local\adaptive_quiz\version.php:

```php
<?php
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$plugin->version  = 2023090900; //version of plugin
$plugin->requires = 2023042400; //version of moodle
$plugin->pluginname = 'Adaptive Quiz';
$plugin->component = 'local_adaptive_quiz';
```

I tried to do a lot of things that *Chat GPT* advised me to do:

- Study the CMS Moodle source code. I have studied. I realized that the CMS creates through, like, the single_button class after it finds this form in JS or the subscribe to event button, but I didn't understand how to subscribe to the event and get the data myself.
- Subscribe to the prepared event through the name of the method, nothing happened.
- Subscribe via $handlers, but he also didn't call the method.

> I check the method through error_log, it is checked by me every time through the callback method - before_footer. Here before_footer works fine.

**Path:** \local\adaptive_quiz\lib.php:

code that checks the plugin for operability:

```php
<?php
 function local_adaptive_quiz_before_footer(){
    error_log('лог сработал');
    return \core\notification::add('Plugin Local adaptive quiz is worked! v8', 
            \core\output\notification::NOTIFY_SUCCESS);
 }
```

code with variable "$handlers":

```php
//code that checks the plugin for operability...

 function local_adaptive_quiz_after_submit($attemptid) {
    error_log('local_adaptive_quiz_after_submit worked');

    //Answer of users...
    $user_responses = "ответы пользователя";

    echo json_encode($user_responses);
}

$handlers = array(
    'quiz_attempt_submitted' => array(
        'handlerfile' => '\local\adaptive_quiz\lib.php',
        'handlerfunction' => 'local_adaptive_quiz_after_submit',
        'schedule' => 'instant',
    ),
);
```

Comment: I don't understand, what is your question ?

Also, chat gpt is fine and dandy but so limited to answer questions about moodle development... It'll be far more usefull and quicker to look at the moodle dev website and its documentation which is ultra complete.

Comment: @Veterini. My question is that my plugin was supposed to subscribe to the "test completion" event, but it didn't respond at all. I wanted to know how to do it right

Comment: If your solution works it's fine but it would be better to follow moodle's way more straightfully (in my own opinion ^^). It can be a hassle some time but in the long run it simplify the work.

First a link to the event API on the official documentation : https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API

From what i see your way doesn't use the API as it should. You should have a corresponding file for each event in local/yourplugin/classes/event.
The event API has all the built in function that records event the right way into moodle.
Can you retrieve your event in the logs event page ?

Comment: it may interest you to check events in this widely used plugin : https://github.com/academic-moodle-cooperation/moodle-mod_offlinequiz/tree/master/classes/event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be quite simple. It was necessary to create using the following path `\local\{name_your_plugin}\db\events.php`, following code:

```php
 $observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname' =>'\mod_quiz\event\attempt_submitted', //name of event
        'includefile' => '\local\adaptive_quiz\classes\attempt_event_submitted_observer.php', //file containing the callback function
        'callback' =>'observe_one', //callback function
        'internal' => false
    ),
 );
```

And along the path (`\local\adaptive_quiz\classes\attempt_event_submitted_observer.php`) that we wrote create a callback function:

```php
function observe_one($event) {
    echo '<h1>observe_one is worked</h1>';
}
```

The main thing is that you need to check the function through the student account. Otherwise the function does not work.

Comment: But Moodle feels like it is overwriting the message, I checked the function through error_log(), so it works.